# JSP include page failing with request.getContextPath()

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I'm trying to include a jsp page in another, and since I don't want to hardcode paths I want to use the request.getContextPath() methods.
But I just can't get it to work. I've tried various things, based on various answers here:

First thing I did was

```
<jsp:include  page="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/structure/Navbar.jsp" />
```

gives me:

```
HTTP Status 500 - /structure/ArtiMarziali/Aikido.jsp (line: 11, column: 24) attribute value for [page] is not properly terminated
```

So I tried:

```
<% String aikido = request.getContextPath() + "/structure/Navbar.jsp"; %>
<jsp:include  page="<%= aikido %>" />
```

throws an exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: File [/ProgettoPW/structure/Navbar.jsp] not found
```

Then:

```
<jsp:include  page="<%= request.getContextPath() + "/structure/Navbar.jsp"  %>" />
```

says I need to escape the quotes, which I can't really do

and

```
<jsp:include  page='<%= request.getContextPath() + "/structure/Navbar.jsp"  %>' />
```

gives the same error as the first one. I tried setting  the result of getContextPath to a variable and using that in the tag, but same errors as before.

I really don't know what the problem i, I need some help, thank you.

(Yes I know that using <%= %> and other scriptlets is frowned upon nowadays, but my course was taught this way and I want to adhere to it for the project)

Edit: This is the file structure, might be useful:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply `<jsp:include  page="/structure/Navbar.jsp" />` ?

Comment: Yes, and it works, but I don't really see why it works if I do it like that but not with getContextPath(). Linking css files and images works fine with it, but not the jsp include. (And as I said, I don't want to use hardcoded paths in case I move things around)

Comment: it works because the path is already relative to the context path so hopefully we have no need to add it

Comment: Oh, yeah. You're right, I completely forgot that. I'm an idiot. Thank you! (If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is already **relative** to the **context path** such that you have no need to add it in your `include` directive (hopefully), which means that this will work:

```
<jsp:include page="/structure/Navbar.jsp" />
```